# CruiseControl.Net Modification Reader Example?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Does anyone have any example of how to use modification reader task?

Ok, I use this over XML:

```
    <modificationReader>
        <filename>mods.xml</filename>
        <path>path/to/my/file/</path>
    </modificationReader>
```

then, what? How do I get the information in "mods.xml" and use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be used with the modificationWriter task which writes the modifications to a file (in the artifact directory by default).

http://build.sharpdevelop.net/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Modification%20Writer%20Task.html

If you're just trying to read in the modifications in to a different projects' buildLog, the above - with a path to the first project - should be sufficient.

Are you trying to do something different?
[CruiseControl.NET: Build subproject obtained by SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833947/cruisecontrol-net-build-subproject-obtained-by-svn/11849796)